# Open file in default app

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have previously used [this way](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/146191/#Comment_146191) to open documents in the default app, but starting from iOS 10 it does not work on iPhone (the app crashes), but it works fine on iPad.

What is the right way to open files from a `DependencyService`?

As I currently have no iOS 10 device to test on, I cannot get the bug.

Comment: this may help you eventually: https://riccardo-moschetti.org/2014/10/03/opening-a-mobile-app-from-a-link-the-xamarin-way-url-schemas/

Comment: Then you have to know the URL scheme

Comment: Can you try it on the simulator and find where the error is occurring? What does "it does not work" mean? (App crashes, nothing happens, Quick Look appears with a blank screen, something else?). I haven't seen any documented changes to the Quick Look framework behavior.

Comment: @dylansturg I tried, but as you can see in the link it is not using Quick Look. But thanks for your help, I got it fixed using Quick Look.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know the URL Scheme for the app that you're attempting to open; URL Schemes are the only way to communicate between apps.

You didn't specify which app you're trying to open, so I've included sample code below that show how to use URL Schemes to open the Settings app, the Mail app and the App Store app (to a specific app).

Apple has [additional documentation on URL Schemes here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html)

```
using UIKit;
using MessageUI;
using Foundation;

using Xamarin.Forms;

using SampleApp.iOS;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(DeepLinks_iOS))]
namespace SampleApp.iOS
{
    public class DeepLinks_iOS : IDeepLinks
    {
        public void OpenStoreLink()
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(new NSUrl("https://appsto.re/us/uYHSab.i")));
        }

        public void OpenFeedbackEmail()
        {
            MFMailComposeViewController mailController;

            if (MFMailComposeViewController.CanSendMail)
            {
                mailController = new MFMailComposeViewController();

                mailController.SetToRecipients(new string[] { "support@gmail.com" });
                mailController.SetSubject("Email Subject String");
                mailController.SetMessageBody("This text goes in the email body", false);

                mailController.Finished += (object s, MFComposeResultEventArgs args) =>
                {
                    args.Controller.DismissViewController(true, null);
                };

                var currentViewController = GetVisibleViewController();
                currentViewController.PresentViewController(mailController, true, null);
            }
        }

        public void OpenSettings()
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(new NSUrl(UIApplication.OpenSettingsUrlString)));
        }


        static UIViewController GetVisibleViewController()
        {
            var rootController = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController;

            if (rootController.PresentedViewController == null)
                return rootController;

            if (rootController.PresentedViewController is UINavigationController)
            {
                return ((UINavigationController)rootController.PresentedViewController).TopViewController;
            }

             if (rootController.PresentedViewController is UITabBarController)
            {
                return ((UITabBarController)rootController.PresentedViewController).SelectedViewController;
            }

            return rootController.PresentedViewController;
        }
    }
}
```